# How to get n rows with highest value for a column without ordering them

Tags: sql, oracle

i have a sql table:

```
C1 | C2 | C3
aa | bb | 21
gg | hh | 53
dd | yy | 37
```

I want the the top 5000 rows with highest value in C3 but I want my data to be ordered by C1
How can I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use the analytical [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/functions156.htm) function:

```
SELECT C1, C2, C3
FROM (
  SELECT C1, C2, C3, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY C3 DESC) AS C3Rank
  FROM myTable
)
WHERE C3Rank <= 500
ORDER BY C1
```